# How to use FINDSTR to search in a specific line?

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I have a file example.txt and a string "Hi" and the beginning of the 15th line.

The required code for findstr should be:

```
findstr /b /n "Hi" "example.txt"
```

Is there something that can search for "Hi" string only in the commanded line (Here 15th).

Please Help !

Comment: Works fine here. Please [edit] your question to include "example.txt" so we have something to test with.

Comment: @DavidPostill He wasn't that clear but he's saying he wants to only search one line. The command he knows will search the whole file

Comment: @barlop Hmm. That really doesn't make any sense. Why search only the 15th line if you already know it's on the 15th line?

Comment: @DavidPostill what if you don't know, and you want to check if it's on the 15th line?

Comment: @barlop If you don't know what? He already said it's on the 15th line "I have a file example.txt and a string "Hi" and the beginning of the 15th line."

Comment: @barlop Does he want to search for a string "Hi" on the start of a line and only return true if it is the 15th line? The question is completely unclear. Any answer is just guessing.

Comment: @DavidPostill  well presumably when he says he has the beginning of the 15th line, he doesn't mean that he knows it's there otherwise there's no point searching.  It looks like he wants to search the 15th line. Now whether he wants to check only at the beginning or not doesn't matter that much 'cos anybody that can answer how to search the 15th line can also say that if he wants to search just the beginning of the line then add a caret(regex symbol for matching the beginning of a line) and make it look at just the beginning they can cover that in their answer easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33523/discussion-between-barlop-and-davidpostill).

Comment: @barlop So we agree that the question should be closed as "unclear what you are asking"

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE you don't know who voted to close it - I didn't.. and I didn't ask him for an example either.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE  Yes I can see what everybody wrote, and I wasn't not giving the questioner a chance. And re "yacking", it makes for further "noise/yacking" when you(or David or I or anybody), add comments after a chat link generated for the purpose of further comments, was automatically provided. So do use the chat link that superuser's automated system provided. I will too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How to use FINDSTR to search in a specific line?**
>
> The required code for findstr should be:
>
> `findstr /b /n "Hi" "example.txt"`
>
> Is there something that can search for "Hi" string only in the
>   commanded line

Based on the wording of your question, I'm going to assume a few things:

1. You want to find a string ONLY and nothing more on a specific line
2. Since your example `FINDSTR` uses the `/B` you string of "Hi" is at the begginning of the line only and then followed by a space for another word, etc. after it.
3. Since your example uses the `/N` swtich, I'm going to assume you only use it to print the lines which the matched strings are found so you can then run about `FINDSTR` command to then get ONLY line 15.

**Here are some example commands (not batch) to run to perform this**

*(You can simple copy and paste all these lines once you variable are plugged in accordingly to run without being a batch script.)*

```
SET SearchFile=C:\Path\example.txt
SET TmpSearchFile=%Temp%\~tmpSearch00.txt
SET String=Hi
SET LineNum=15

FINDSTR /B /N "%String%" "%SearchFile%" > "%TmpSearchFile%"
FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=: " %A IN (`"FINDSTR /B "%LineNum%:%String%" "%TmpSearchFile%""`) DO ECHO %~A
```

This basically pipes the first `FINDSTR` with the line number of the matching string at the beginning of all lines to a temp file (if it exists, it is overwritten). It then searches that temp file for the string of the line number, plus a colon and the string (i.e. "15:Hi"). Afterwards, I used a `FOR /F` loop making the `colon` and a `space` the `delimiter` with a `token` of `2`. It will then `ECHO` the string ONLY as you request (replace `ECHO` with some other command if needed).

Comment: Wow, this answer was just accepted today; that's a record for me from the time I answered until the time accepted. Just adding the comment for reference with this regard for my own personal FYI

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this with batch, but I might with Powershell.

To determine whether the 15th line of a file started with the string 'Hi', I would use:

```
if (Get-Content -Path x:\pathto\file.txt -First 15 `
    | Select-Object -Last 1 `
    | Select-String -Pattern '^Hi' -Quiet)
{
    # do my thing here...
}
```

This should ensure that the whole file isn't read, just the first 15 lines.

Of course, the 15th line is arbitrary.  Depending on where you actually want to look, you might want to tweak the parameters to `Get-Content` and `Select-Object` to reduce the amount of reads.